# Calculating the black height of a red-black tree

Tags: go, data-structures, tree, red-black-tree

Maybe because it's late, maybe because I've been staring at code all day, I'm not sure... but I'm trying to write a function in Go to calculate the height of a red-black tree. I haven't written a red-black tree, or any tree, in a few years; so I wanted to practice, as well as get better at Go via writing a Go package dedicated to various tree implementations (BST, RBT, AVL, Trie, min/max/binomial/fibonacci heaps...)

I want to write this function to ensure that the red-black tree invariant "all paths from a node to its nil descendants contain the same number of black nodes" is maintained in my tree. Here's what I have currently:

```golang
// IsBalanced returns a bool representing whether
// all paths from a node to its nil descendants contain
// the same number of black nodes.
func (tree *RBT) IsBalanced() bool {
    if tree.IsEmpty() {
        return true
    }

    height := tree.Root().blackHeight()
    if height != 0 {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

// blackHeight returns an int representing the black height from a given node
func (node *Node) blackHeight() int {
    if node == nil {
        return 1
    }

    leftBlackHeight := node.leftChild().blackHeight()
    rightBlackHeight := node.rightChild().blackHeight()

    if leftBlackHeight != rightBlackHeight {
        return 0
    }

    if node.getColor() == BLACK {
        leftBlackHeight++
    }

    return leftBlackHeight
}
```

I guess I'm asking for some code review here... does my IsBalanced (and by extension my helper function blackHeight) actually return a truthful statement (that is, can I rely on these functions to tell me if the invariant is maintained)? And if not, can someone give me some pointers as to how best to calculate the black-height of a red-black tree?

Thanks!

**--EDIT--**
I've added a test for my IsBalanced function:

```golang
func TestRBT_IsBalanced(t *testing.T) {
    tree := NewWithIntComparator()
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < 31; i++ {
        key := rand.Int()
        _, err := tree.Insert(key, i)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf(err.Error())
        }
    }

    if !tree.IsBalanced() {
        t.Errorf("tree is not balanced")
    }
}
```

The test above fails exactly as it is written (inserting 31 random integers). However, the test succeeds when I insert 10 random integers. Test fails again when I insert 7 random integers.

So I suppose my issue lies in my Insert function. Here's that:

```golang
// Insert takes a key and a value of type interface, and inserts a new Node with that key and value.
// The function inserts by key; that is, the key of the new node is
// compared against current nodes to find the correct insertion point.
// The function returns the newly inserted node's key or an error, if there was one.
func (tree *RBT) Insert(key, value interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    newNode := NewNode(key, value, -1)

    // tree is empty, so we set the new node as the root and increase the size of the tree by 1.
    if tree.IsEmpty() {
        newNode.setColor(BLACK) // Case 0: recolor the root
        tree.setRoot(newNode)
        tree.setSize(tree.Size() + 1)
        return newNode.key(), nil
    }

    // key already exists in the tree
    if tree.Search(key) {
        return nil, NewDuplicateError(key)
    }

    parent := new(Node)     // this will eventually be set as the newNode's parent
    tempNode := tree.Root() // to determine when we've hit a leaf
    for tempNode != nil {
        parent = tempNode
        compare := tree.comparator(newNode.key(), parent.key())
        switch {
        case compare < 0:
            tempNode = tempNode.leftChild()
        case compare > 0:
            tempNode = tempNode.rightChild()
        }
    }

    newNode.setParent(parent)
    compare := tree.comparator(newNode.key(), parent.key())
    switch {
    case compare < 0:
        parent.setLeftChild(newNode)
    case compare > 0:
        parent.setRightChild(newNode)
    }

    newNode.setRightChild(nil)
    newNode.setLeftChild(nil)
    newNode.setColor(RED)
    tree.insertFixup(newNode)
    tree.setSize(tree.Size() + 1)

    return newNode.key(), nil
}
```

Here's tree.insertFixup():

```golang
// insertFixup performs rotations and recolorations after insertion.
// Cases:
// 1. newNode's uncle is red: recolor node's parent, grandparent, and uncle.
// 2. newNode's uncle is black (triangle): rotate node's parent in
// the opposite direction of newNode's placement.
// 3. newNode's uncle is black (line): rotate node's grandparent in
// the opposite direction of newNode's placement, then recolor original parent and grandparent.
func (tree *RBT) insertFixup(node *Node) {
    for node.getParent().getColor() == RED {
        uncle, side := node.uncle()
        if side == RIGHT {
            if uncle.getColor() == RED { // case 1
                node.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                uncle.recolor()
                node.grandparent().setColor(RED)
                node = node.grandparent()
            } else if node == node.getParent().rightChild() { // case 2
                node = node.getParent()
                tree.leftRotate(node)
            } else { // case 3
                node.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                node.grandparent().setColor(RED)
                tree.rightRotate(node)
            }
        } else if side == LEFT {
            if uncle.getColor() == RED { // case 1
                node.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                uncle.recolor()
                node.grandparent().setColor(RED)
                node = node.grandparent()
            } else if node == node.getParent().leftChild() { // case 2
                node = node.getParent()
                tree.rightRotate(node)
            } else { // case 3
                node.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                node.grandparent().setColor(RED)
                tree.leftRotate(node)
            }
        }
    }
    tree.Root().setColor(BLACK)
}
```

And finally, here's my left rotate:

```golang
func (tree *RBT) leftRotate(node *Node) {
    newParent := node.rightChild()
    node.setRightChild(newParent.leftChild())
    if newParent.leftChild() != nil {
        newParent.leftChild().setParent(node)
    }
    newParent.setParent(node.getParent())
    if node.isRoot() {
        tree.setRoot(newParent)
    } else if node == node.getParent().leftChild() {
        node.getParent().setLeftChild(newParent)
    } else {
        node.getParent().setRightChild(newParent)
    }
    newParent.setLeftChild(node)
    node.setParent(newParent)
}
```

and my right rotate:

```golang
func (tree *RBT) rightRotate(node *Node) {
    newParent := node.leftChild()
    node.setLeftChild(newParent.rightChild())
    if newParent.rightChild() != nil {
        newParent.rightChild().setParent(node)
    }
    newParent.setParent(node.getParent())
    if node.isRoot() {
        tree.setRoot(newParent)
    } else if node == node.getParent().rightChild() {
        node.getParent().setRightChild(newParent)
    } else {
        node.getParent().setLeftChild(newParent)
    }
    newParent.setRightChild(node)
    node.setParent(newParent)
}
```

Here's my helper function uncle():

```golang
// uncle returns a node's uncle and a side flag, for use in insertFixup.
func (node *Node) uncle() (*Node, int) {
    // return grandparent's right child
    if node.grandparent().leftChild() == node.getParent() {
        return node.grandparent().rightChild(), RIGHT
    }
    // else return grandparent's left child
    return node.grandparent().leftChild(), LEFT
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a better question to ask of a test, than to ask of us?  I find the go's statically typed, compiled nature and some well written tests to be a reassuring combination.  https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/add-a-test

Comment: I have added a test: 


`func TestRBT_IsBalanced(t *testing.T) {
 tree := NewWithIntComparator()
 rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
 for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
  key := rand.Int()
  _, err := tree.Insert(key, i)
  if err != nil {
   t.Errorf(err.Error())
  }
 }

 if !tree.IsBalanced() {
  t.Errorf("tree is not balanced")
 }
}`


God, that formatting is ugly. 

It returns true for some number of nodes and false for others... Which either means my insertion algorithm is incorrect or my black height algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: Instead of posting that as a comment, edit your question and add this as additional information. Please also add a concrete example input for which the output is wrong.

Comment: NB: your code seems correct, so if you get invalid RB trees, your `Insert` method has problems. You might want to focus your question on that, but be sure to provide a concrete sequence of insertions that yields an invalid RB tree (also after checking the actual tree yourself "manually" with paper and pen). And of course, add the relevant code (`Insert` and its dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that in case 3, I was right rotating on the current node itself, when I should've been rotating on the node's grandparent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).